# Reading data from different upstream systems in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdbms

How to handle data ingestion in spark if data is received from multiple sources systems like RDBMS or sometimes from CSV files or any other file format or upstream systems.

If file format is known then it can be specified while reading as `spark.read.csv` or `spark.read.jdbc`. But if it is dynamic, then how to handle data ingestion?

Comment: JDBC doesn't have a "file format". Please clarify "dynamic". Are you referring to file extensions, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is an option as in the following code snippets:

## CSV

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("data/books.csv");
```

Source: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch08/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch08/lab100_mysql_ingestion/MySQLToDatasetWithOptionsApp.java

## JDBC

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila")
    .option("dbtable", "actor")
    .option("user", "root")
    .option("password", "Spark<3Java")
    .option("useSSL", "false")
    .option("serverTimezone", "EST")
    .format("jdbc")
    .load();
```

Source: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jgp/books/spark/ch01/lab100_csv_to_dataframe/CsvToDataframeApp.java

You could read all those information from a configuration file. Each read will also result in a unique dataframe, so you could keep an array, a map, or a list of all those dataframes once ingested.

Comment: This doesn't answer the part of the question about dynamic inputs

Comment: It does in the way I understood the question… but you also asked for clarification, so…

Comment: Dynamic means today from one source system like  rdbms, tomorrow same data from files or any other source with different delimiter.

Comment: Yeah, so my solution should work… you need the configuration somewhere, so read it from there and dynamically create your “reader” as described above.